# mount nfs failing

Tags: macos, mount, nfs

Mounting an nfs storage is failing today, when it worked fine yesterday.

```
sudo mount -v -o rw storage01:/storage/_shares/ci 
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/bemehiser/Projects/data/ci

mount_nfs: can't mount /storage/_shares/ci from storage01 onto 
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/bemehiser/Projects/data/ci: Permission denied
mount: /System/Volumes/Data/Users/bemehiser/Projects/data/ci failed with 13
```

I don't think any configurations changed. I never even unmounted the storage between yesterday and today. I've tried unmounting the mount (not mounted), deleting the ci dir and recreating it, checking all the permissions, sudo, no sudo, restarting the entire computer, etc. No dice.

The mount works on an older macOS 10.14 vm, but not my macOS 10.15.2 MacBook Pro

Any suggestions would be appreciated.